# View/View subtree changed listener API

Tags: android, view, listener, monkeypatching

I'm trying to write a debug utility that will take certain actions (logging, screenshots, etc...) when a view in the current Activity's view hierarchy changes. Change here is anything that would result in the visual representation of the view tree to change: setting the text on a TextView, changing the background color on a View, or adding/removing children to/from a ViewGroup.

Ideally, I'm looking for an API that will notify me when these changes are about to occur and what view/view subtree they will be effecting.

I've spent a lot of time looking at possible solutions and the cleanest would be to use ViewTreeObserver's OnPreDrawListener and OnGlobalLayoutListener. They seem to be notified when the events of interest occur. However, they do not provide any context information as to which views are affected. AFAIK attaching these listeners to a view's ViewTreeObserver results in the notifications being fired whenever anything in the view tree changes and there is no way to create isolated ViewTreeObservers for individual views. This means that I would have to traverse the entire view tree at each notification to determine which property was changed.

Another approach would be to binary patch the View classes so that they callback to my API in methods like `setBackgroundColor` or any other methods of interest. [android-aspectj](https://code.google.com/p/android-aspectj/) could be used for that. The downside here is that this would only work for classes that I compiled and so is next to useless since I could just modify the source directly. Along the same idea, [dexmaker](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) would be a more complete solution as it allows for patching the classes at runtime. Here, however, we run into the problems of class loading. To patch the class I would have to load it through my own `ClassLoader` but all of the View classes would have already been loaded in by Android. One solution would be to clone the view tree after it was created but instead of using the stock loaded classes, use my own patched classes. This would almost work except for situations where the app has grabbed references to the view tree before my patching has been put into place. Of course I would also have to redo the clone at each layout change event (adding/removing views). I understand that this process would be slow but so far it is the most transparent and most complete solution.

Finally, and this is probably the most difficult approach, is there a way to use the method tracing system built into Android ([Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)) to receive trace events at runtime? Currently the system will dump the trace to a file on the SD card for offline processing. That is obviously too late for my needs but it would be nice if there were hooks exposed in the native SDK for intercepting these events.

Any and all suggestions are welcome. At this point I am not even looking for portable solutions so feel free to mention any reflaction/hidden API tricks. Thanks for reading this behemoth of a post.